# SoftLayer API -- local parameter of getSummaryData

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get CPU, Memory, Network data using getSummaryData. (service: SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_object)
URL:http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData

"validType" parameter of "getSummaryData" have keyName, Name, summaryType, unit properties.(datatype: SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type)
URL:http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type

My question:

1. I want to know value of these parameters. I know value of following. Please tell me if there are other value in each case.

   - In CPU case:
     KeyName : CPU0,CPU1,...,CPUn
     Name : cpu
     summaryType: average/max/sum
   - In Memory case: 
     KeyName : MEMORY_USAGE
     Name : memory_usage
     summaryType: average/max/sum
   - In Network case: 
     KeyName : PUBLICIN_NET_OCTET/PUBLICOUT_NET_OCTET/PRIVATEIN_NET_OCTET/PRIVATEOUT_NET_OCTET
     Name : publicIn_net_octet/publicOut_net_octet/privateIn_net_octet/privateOut_net_octet
     summaryType: average/max/sum
2. Would I use to the "unit" parameter?
   I tried to change to value of "unit" parameter. I tried set "GB" but value of "counter" was no change.  (Please refer the CURL command and parameter of following )
   Please tell me valid value of "unit" parameter if "unit" parameter is enable.

**curl**

```
curl -K "config file" -X POST -d @"parameter" 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/"object id"/getSummaryData.json'
```

**parameter**
*pattern1*

```
{"parameters":["08/16/2016", "08/16/2016",[{"keyName":"MEMORY_USAGE","summaryType":"max","unit":"GB"}],600]}
```

*pattern2*

```
{"parameters":["08/16/2016", "08/16/2016",[{"keyName":"MEMORY_USAGE","summaryType":"max","unit":"KB"}],600]}
```

*pattern3*

```
{"parameters":["08/16/2016", "08/16/2016",[{"keyName":"MEMORY_USAGE","summaryType":"max"}],600]}
```

**ADDITIONAL:**
I executed "getMetricDataTypes".
KeyName and name is OK but summaryType is counter and average only. sum and max is nothing.
Is there other summaryType?

Comment: All the summary types that you can use are displayed. There not exist another summaryType that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values parameters, try this method:

- [SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getMetricDataTypes](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getMetricDataTypes)

Regarding to **unit** property:

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set this property to get other kind of type of value

Comment: I added the results of the trial in question.